# Matlab: Examine objects from different workspaces

Tags: matlab, debugging

I often wish that I could examine objects from different workspaces in call stack to compare.  Is there a way to do this?  Right now, I have to mangle the code force a return, returning function output variables so that I am back at the base workspace, then use openvar to compare the returned object with something in the base workspace.

In a pinch, I could save the workspace from with a possibly deeply nested function while in debug mode, then mangle to the code (less) to force a return to the base workspace, then load the saved workspace.  I'm wishing there was a way to force a return without mangling the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command`assignin` to copy a variable to the base workspace for a comparison.

For example, if you want to copy a variable in your code called `a`, and in the base workspace have it called `b`, use `assignin('base', 'b', a)`.

You can either include this command directly within your code, or you can enter it manually at the command line while in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the variable you want to compare to in the base workspace, then you can use the [`evalin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) function to fetch it for a comparison. For example, let's say you have a variable `ground_truth` in the base workspace, and a variable `result` in an arbitrarily-nested function. From that function, you could compare them for equality like so:

```
resultsMatch = isequal(result, evalin('base', 'ground_truth'));
```

Comment: Thanks, that should help.  Normally, however, I need to examine the contents to see the cause of discrepancies, so I need to store the result in a variable in order to use openvar.  For the longest while now, Matlab will not create new variables when the debugger has halted execution within a function.

Comment: I get that there are complications from changing the variables in a function's workspace, but at the same time, I seem to be able to assign anything at all to an existing variable, including a struct with member properties created on the fly (i.e., during debugging) to store objects/results generated by command line statements.  So it seems the restriction is easily circumvented by creating a dummy variable in each function, or cannibalizing an existing variable that is no longer needed in the code that follows the point at which the debugger halted.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the two answers already added you might find [this FEX submission](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46165-comparevars) useful for comparing variables.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  That should prove helpful in the future.